# C Pointers, some variables return actual value of variable pointed to, others seem to point to memory addresses

Tags: c, pointers

I'm working on a program in C which is intended to store information pertaining to a car rental business (reads in information in a loop, and outputs each entered customer per iteration, once the loop breaks, some average statistics are calculated and returned), I've had little issues up until I've tried to add calculations for the averages displayed in the end of the program and a few new variable pointers (and variables in main to adjoin) to facilitate this

My values for `name, license, serviceCost, dayCount3, totalIncome` all seem to pass and output correctly.

However, my values for `dayCount1, dayCount2, avgdays` do not and seem to return arbitrary information (it looks like a memory address as an int, but I'm not certain)

As far as i can tell, there is no differentiation in how i treat the pointers and their associated variables which do pass as expected and those that do not. I am new at working with pointers and have only had experience in C# and Java previously in which I've never worked with pointers.

Here is the code I'm currently working with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//Get input from the user, performing some checks on the data to ensure correct ranges. Uses pass by pointer
void getInput(char *initial, int *license, int *rentalPeriod) 
{
    //Prompts user for initial and checks that it's a valid alpha charecter
    printf("Please enter an initial.\n");
    scanf(" %c%*c", initial);
    while (isalpha(*initial) == 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid alphabetical initial:\n");
        scanf(" %c%*c", initial);
    }

    //Prompts user for license number and checks for acceptable range. (x >= 1 , x <= 999999999)
    printf("Please enter your License #:\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", license);
    while (*license <= 0 || *license >= 1000000000) 
    {
        printf("Your license number was invalid %c, please enter a value between 1 and 999999999\n", *initial);
        scanf(" %d%*c", license);
    }
    
    //Prompts user for rental period, then checks that rental time is above 0 days.
    printf("How many days would your like to rent for %c?\n", *initial);
    scanf("%d&*c", rentalPeriod);
    while(*rentalPeriod <= 0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a rental period, with a value in whole days and a minimum value of 1\n");
        scanf(" %d%*c", rentalPeriod);
    }

    return;
}

//Takes the rental period determined by the user input and sets it to a series of conditions in order to determine the mathematical equation with which to charge the customer.
void processRates(int *rentalPeriod, int *dayCount1, int *dayCount2, int *dayCount3, float *serviceCost,  float *totalIncome, int *totalDays) 
{
    //Declare const variables needed for computation
    float const DAILYRATE1 = 34.50f;
    float const DAILYRATE2 = 30.50f;
    float const DAILYRATE3 = 22.50f;


    //Logic block used to determine the arithmetic applied to the rental period to derive costs
    if(*rentalPeriod >= 1 && *rentalPeriod <= 3)
    {
        *serviceCost = *rentalPeriod * DAILYRATE1; 
        (*dayCount1)++;
    }
    else if (*rentalPeriod > 3 && *rentalPeriod <= 7)
    {
        *serviceCost = 3 * DAILYRATE1 + (*rentalPeriod - 3) * DAILYRATE2;
        (*dayCount2)++;
    }
    else if (*rentalPeriod > 7) 
    {
        *serviceCost = 3 * DAILYRATE1 + 4 * DAILYRATE2 + (*rentalPeriod - 7) * DAILYRATE3;
        (*dayCount3)++;

    } 

    *totalIncome = *totalIncome + *serviceCost;
    *totalDays = *totalDays + *rentalPeriod;

    return;
}

//Display costs to user
void displayServiceCosts(char *initial, int *license, int *rentalPeriod, float *serviceCosts)
{
    printf("           Summary of Hire:\n        ----------------------\n        Customer: %c\n        License #: %d\n        Days rented: %d\n        Rental Cost is $%.2f\n\n"
    , *initial, *license, *rentalPeriod, *serviceCosts);
}

void displayHireStats(int *dayCount1, int *dayCount2, int *dayCount3, float avgDays, float *totalIncome)
{
    printf("          Statistics of Hire Activities\n        ---------------------------\n         Days Hired less than 4 : %d\n         Days hired between 4&7 days: %d\n         Days hired greater than 7 days: %d\n         The average days hired is: %.2f days\n         Total rent received: $%.2f\n", 
    *dayCount1, *dayCount2, *dayCount3, avgDays, *totalIncome);
}

int main () 
{
    //Declare needed variables
    char name;
    int license, rentalPeriod, totalDays, dayCount1, dayCount2, dayCount3;
    int const N = 7;
    float totalIncome, serviceCost, avgDays;

    for(int counter = 0; counter < N; counter++)
    {
        //Get Input
        getInput(&name, &license, &rentalPeriod);

        //Proccess input and assign to a variable
        processRates(&rentalPeriod, &dayCount1, &dayCount2, &dayCount3, &serviceCost, &totalIncome, &totalDays);

        //Return output relating to service in its entirety
        displayServiceCosts(&name, &license, &rentalPeriod, &serviceCost);

    }

    avgDays = totalDays / N;
    displayHireStats(&dayCount1, &dayCount2, &dayCount3, avgDays, &totalIncome);

    return(0);
}
```

The output of the following program is as below, as I stated earlier, I believe the data which is shown incorrectly is actually the memory address of the pointer rather than any calculation on the value (The output above the statistics of hire are included just as an example of the output and proof of the other variables working)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFgWx.png)

Thank you for any and all input!

Comment: its because you dont initialize them

Comment: Where in the code do i initialize the other values that do pass correctly though, i could understand if each of the different values has been treated differently, but as far as i can see programmatically I treat both the same.

i,e Why would dayCount3 pass but not dayCount1 or dayCount2?

Comment: some of the value are directly initialized through scanf so you dont need to. For daycount3 you were just lucky that the register was holding 0 as a value.

Comment: Also you didn't get the average right, you have to cast N as float when making the division to make it a real average, see my edit

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense, I was under the impression though that if we declare int then the default value would associate to 0 (assuming we don't initialize another) as a float would become 0.0f, is this incorrect in the case of working with pointer because the pointer initializes but not the value it points to, or is something else at play here?

Comment: Addresses are allocated randomly by the system so you dont need to initialize them. The value that they point to is, unless you had assigned a value yourself, totally random, could be 0 (often), could be 1234567, anything is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C you have to initialize your variables, else they will pick garbage value located in the register.

You can easily fix this with:

```
int license = 0; // well this one and some other one initialized through scanf are not necessary.
int rentalPeriod = 0;
int totalDays = 0;
int const N = 2; // switch it back to 7
float totalIncome = 0.0f;
float serviceCost = 0.0f; 
float avgDays = 0.0f;
int dayCount1 = 0;
int dayCount2 = 0;
int dayCount3 = 0;
```

output:

```
Please enter an initial.
a
Please enter your License #:
345345
How many days would your like to rent for a?
4
           Summary of Hire:
        ----------------------
        Customer: a
        License #: 345345
        Days rented: 4
        Rental Cost is $134.00

Please enter an initial.
b
Please enter your License #:
6456456
How many days would your like to rent for b?
3
           Summary of Hire:
        ----------------------
        Customer: b
        License #: 6456456
        Days rented: 3
        Rental Cost is $103.50

          Statistics of Hire Activities
        ---------------------------
         Days Hired less than 4 : 1
         Days hired between 4&7 days: 1
         Days hired greater than 7 days: 0
         The average days hired is: 3.00 days
         Total rent received: $237.50
```

NB: You also need to cast N to float and change to `avgDays = totalDays / (float)N;` to get the correct avgDays output